Bare copper conductor for grounding a sub panel
Several years ago, my father converted a 240V sub panel to 120V by re-purposing one of the 3 available conductors for the ground wire and using the other 2 conductors for the hot and neutral.
Now he needs 240V back at that location but wants to also retain the 120V circuits.  His idea is to use bare #4 copper wire (of which he has sufficient material on hand) to provide the grounding conductor for this sub panel.  Will this be an acceptable solution?  If he uses the bare conductor, must it be encased in conduit or can it be run, and supported, parallel to the existing Romex without conduit or other protection?
I'm not worried about an inspection but I do want to ensure he is safe and doesn't cause a shock or potential fire.

Can you tell us what thickness of wire your father currently has running to that subpanel? And share a picture of the inside of the subpanel? Please edit the question to include this.

Newer code allows for a separate ground wire for receptacles/lights, but not sure if it includes sub panels.  The feed breaker amps will be the limiting factor if 4 gauge ground is large enough, but is quite large and should be enough except for large amp(over 100 amps) panels.  Panels in detached buildings also require ground rods.

Current conductor is 6 AWG Romex.  I'm not able to get a panel pic but I it is wired with a breaker serving as a disconnect, the "grounding" wire is connected to a ground bus inside the box, and the neutral conductor is connected to an isolated neutral bus.  Location is in a basement shop at other end of 70' house from main panel.

I'm confident on the necessary ampacities, and I know that bare grounding conductors are sometimes used.  I'm just trying to figure out if I can run 70' of bare 4 AWG grounding conductor from this sub panel to the main panel.  I'm sure that this arrangement would be acceptable if all the existing conductors were THHN or similar encased within conduit along with a bare copper grounding conductor; I'm focused on the acceptability/suitability of a bare "unprotected" 4 AWG conductor running parallel to the existing Romex.

Romex/similar cables need protection from damage inside of a house below 8 feet.  The protection is usually having it inside walls or some protection provided by conduit/made wooden box.  Above 8 feet it is usually allowed to be just supported to the ceiling joists.    This question seems to say a separate(not in the cable) ground wire might be okay, but still want one of the experts to say so.   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/66758/grounding-requirements-for-main-panel-and-subpanel?rq=1

I'm confused about this "Romex" you're describing. In my (limited) experience "Romex" cable always has a bare ground wire included, and you're not allowed to use that bare wire for anything other than ground. What wires exactly are contained in this "Romex" of yours? Are they all individually insulated and none of them bare?

@crip659 The NEC allows retrofitting ground only if the original installation was compliant at the time without a ground wire. Retrofitting rules won’t help if the installation was illegal to begin with.

The Romex (NM-B, actually) that is in place is a 3 conductor jacketed cable, 6 AWG.  The original installation was to supply 240V ONLY, and that was, primarily, to provide a disconnect to an outbuilding that no longer exists.  There was, in addition to the 240V circuit continuing to the outbuilding, also a 3-prong 240V welding outlet.  The circuit to the outbuilding is no longer in use and, basically, my father wants to return the 240V welding outlet to use (but with the ability to provide a chassis/equipment ground) as well as retain the 120V outlets that are connected to the sub panel.

As an expansion on the above, the outbuilding was several hundred feet away and had it's own path to ground via ground rods installed at that outbuilding.  That allowed a normal (safe) 120V installation as well as 240V service in that outbuilding.  That's also (I imagine) the reason only a 3C cable was installed to the sub panel - to save money at the time over a 4C cable, as the 4C cable wasn't really needed for the existing use case(s) in place 35 years ago.

@MickeyElam - When you say the original cable is a 3 conductor cable, do you mean it has three copper wires in a jacket (typically black, white, and uninsulated ground) or it has 3 insulated wires (typically black, red, and white plus an uninsulated ground?  If the first one, you'll need to replace the cable because you don't have enough conductors.

@Mark - The existing cable has 3 conductors - black, red, white - and no grounding conductor.  My father is trying to avoid replacing the existing cable by laying in the bare 4 AWG copper alongside the existing NM cable.  The bare #4 will be run either within walls or stapled/supported to the bottom of existing floor joists from the sub panel location to the main service panel.  All this is, basically, as described in the original question...
